# How Can I Create a Space-Delimited String from JSON?

Tags: json, azure-devops, jq

I am doing some work with **Azure Devops (ADO)** Variable Groups and I would like to query an existing Variable Group to get all its variables to build a list of parameters to send to ADO CLI method.

Here is the JSON representation of an existing Variable Group:

```
{
  "authorized": true,
  "description": "test",
  "name": "TESTGROUP",
  "providerData": null,
  "type": "Vsts",
  "variables": {
    "app_container_environment": {
      "value": "dev"
    },
    "aws_region": {
      "value": "us-west-2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**
What I'd like to do is use **jq** to read each variable definition and extract the variable name and value. Then, I'd build a string prefixed by "**--variables**" followed by a list of all the key/value pairs,  space-delimited as follows:

**--variables app_container_environment="dev" aws_region="us-west-2"**

Note that the list begins with "**--variables**" followed by a key/value pair delimited by a space between each key/value pair.

I have tried to use **join** which is kind of close.  But the main problem I'm having is due to the way the JSON is structured. I'm not sure how to refer to the variable name.  The value element is easy to get, but I can't seem to get it's parent(e.g. the variable name).  For example, "**us-west-2**" value's variable name is "**aws_region**".

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample, the invocation:

```
jq -r '
  .variables
  | [to_entries[]
     | "\(.key)=\"\(.value.value|tostring)\""]
  | "--variables " + join(" ")
' sample.json
```

produces:

```
--variables app_container_environment="dev" aws_region="us-west-2"
```